# Mongoose $gte doesn't work for aggregation

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want go find data with aggregation and limit by date, but I can't find what I am doing wrong. I need agregation, because in full code I am using group, so find is no go for me.

Here is simple version of code:

```
const dateMonth = new Date();
dateMonth.setDate(dateMonth.getDate() - 10); // Last 10 days
const dateLimit = new Date(dateMonth).toISOString();

const resultScore = await ModelScoreUser.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    createdAt: {$gt: dateLimit}
  }
}]);

const resultScore1 = await ModelScoreUser.find({createdAt: {$gt: dateLimit}});
```

resultScore  is [].
I try with find, just for check if date is OK and resultScore1 gives me correct result.
I am loosing my mind and I by now, I am sure that this is database bug :)
I am using "mongoose": "^5.9.20",

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a `$expr` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RdJLRGck8Dp)

Comment: The code you show looks like it should work.  What does the schema look like?

Comment: You must compare `Date` values with `Date` value, not with **strings**. Remove the `.toISOString()`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to work with Date values, then I recommend a Date library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)

Would be as simple as this:

```
const resultScore = await ModelScoreUser.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    createdAt: {$gte: DateTime.now().minus({days: 10}).startOf('day').toJSDate() }
  }
}]);
```